# How to dynamically scroll in Tlistbox Delphi xe5

Tags: ios, delphi, listbox, delphi-xe5, firemonkey-fm3

TListbox.topIndex is not apparent in Delphi xe5. How do I perform a similar function ? I would like to have the listbox scroll so that the selected item is at the top of the listbox.

I have found other examples where I can set ListBox.itemIndex, but that doesn't scroll so that the selected item is at the top of the listbox.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this code which works:

```
var
  THackListBox = type TListBox;
begin
  THackListBox(ListBox1).VScrollBar.Value := 0;
```

The VScrollBar property is protected but this method exposes the property and allows the value to be set to zero.

Comment: Don't you mean `type` not `var`?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, the VCL `TListBox` has a public `TopIndex` property, which internally uses the [`LB_SETTOPINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

There is no equivalent in the FireMonkey `TListBox`.  The only option I see would be to call the ListBox's `ScrollTo()` method to manually scroll the ListBox so the target list item appears where you want it to be.